# Why is bash "find" utility 100x slower on some of my OSX machines?

Tags: bash, macos, performance, find

I interact with 6 Mac minis used for data acquisition at remote sites. I wrote a bash script that uses the bash "find" utility to make an inventory of data files, but I found that on two of the computers, the "find" step is about 100x slower than on the others.

The test command I am using is:

```
time find . -type f > /dev/null
```

One computer takes 0.5 seconds to find 201,000 files; another takes 49 seconds to find 184,000 files.

I checked that both the number of files and sub-directories in the data directory are roughly the same. The operating systems are old, but the slow computers are running a newer OSX (10.8.5) than one of the faster ones (10.6.8). The slowest computer has a 2.5 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM; the fastest computer has a 2.4 GHz processor and 2 GB of RAM. All the computers are running the same version of the same proprietary data-acquisition software, with similar processing loads.

I also did a disc-writing speed test using "dd", as suggested at http://www.amsys.co.uk/2013/04/using-command-line-to-benchmark-disks/. There was no real difference between the systems.

So if it isn't the OS or the hardware, and the number of files being found is about the same, what could account for such a huge difference in performance?

Comment: Disk caching. If something's read the same data recently, it's much faster. Try it twice in a row and compare then.

Comment: Good thought, but repeated attempts don't seem to make any difference to the speed.

Comment: Can you trace them and see if one version is using `lstat` on each file to determine whether or not it's a directory, while the other doesn't?

Comment: Are you maybe acquiring onto a FAT formatted disk on the slow machines and HFS+ on the faster ones?

Comment: `find` has nothing to do with `bash`, it is NOT a `bash` utility, it a separate program that can be run from any language.  The best you could say is that it is commonly run from `bash`, that's all.

Comment: Check your hard drive health, may be is not that good :p

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I'm not totally sure how to interpret the partition information, but "diskutil list" shows the same partition types for partitions 0, 1, 2, and 3 on disk0 ("GUID_partition_scheme", "EFI", "Apple_CoreStorage", "Apple_Boot") on all the computers, both slow and fast, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, the OSX "Disk Utility" (I think that's what it was called) has a "First Aid" button; I pressed that, and the report that came out said that it seemed the disc was "fine". Are there other tests you can suggest? Command-line ones would be the most useful--I tried downloading a disc diagnostics app from the App Store, but it wasn't compatible with the older OS, so I couldn't install it.

Comment: @thatotherguy, "tracing" sounds like a useful thing, but I'm not familiar with it. A little googling led me to try `(set -x; find .  > /dev/null)`, but the only output from that was "++ find .", which doesn't seem to help. Am I misunderstanding what you meant when you said to "trace" the commands?

Comment: @Kevin I meant system call tracing, as with `dtruss` or `strace`.

Comment: @thatotherguy, okay, I'm new to this, so I hope I'm doing it right. strace doesn't exist on my Macs, but dtruss does. For some reason, dtruss output goes to stderror, but I was able to redirect it so I could grep the output. `sudo dtruss find . 2> /dev/stdout | grep lstat` results in lines like this: `lstat64(".\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF8F0, 0x0)   = 0 0` on all the computers (fast and slow). Does this mean that all the computers are using "lstat" when "find" is invoked as you suggested?

Comment: @Kevin You can do `sudo dtruss find . 2>&1 > /dev/null | wc -l` or so to count the number of syscalls, and just make sure it's not dramatically much higher on one. In the old days, `find` had to query each file to determine whether it was a directory to descend into. Multiple optimizations were added to avoid this, but they didn't always apply the same (readdir extensions could be missing metadata on certain fs, hard link counting could be ineffectual based on underlying enumeration order)

Comment: @thatotherguy. Oddly, the number of syscalls is very different on the different machines, despite similar numbers of files, but this has no apparent relationship to the speed of `find`. One of the slow machines made 22 times as many syscalls as the other machines, but another of the slow machines made about the average number of syscalls.